# Is there a reason why I'm getting a list index out of range when I'm seeing it is very much in range?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python and am having trouble with lists, specifically printing specific index's.

I honestly don't know really what to try. I've attempted retyping the code, double checked my spaces, and format. Just not sure what else I can check as I am new.

```
wizard_list = ['spider legs, toe of frog, eye of newt, bat wing, slug butter, snake dandruff']
print(wizard_list)
['spider legs, toe of frog, eye of newt, bat wing, slug butter, snake dandruff']


print(wizard_list[2])    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(wizard_list[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected:

```
print(wizard_list[2]) # to print eye of newt
```

Actual:

```
print(wizard_list[2]) # displays IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your list is just one long string. Try `'spider legs', 'toe of frog',...`

Comment: There is only one element in that list. That element is `'spider legs, toe of frog, eye of newt, bat wing, slug butter, snake dandruff'`.

Answer (score 1):

When Python detects a new ' or " character it transforms everything after it to string, then when you close it with another ' character you delimit what part of your code belongs to a string. 
In your case, you created a list with only one big string, because you only put two ' characters. To test it you can do:

```
len(wizard_list)
> 1
```

The way you want it is:

```
wizard_list = ['spider legs', 'toe of frog', 'eye of newt', 'bat wing', 'slug butter', 'snake dandruff']
```

Now python will be able to understand that these commas are separating different elements inside a list and not just characters inside a string.

You can test it with the previous command:

```
len(wizard_list)
>6
```

Now the length of the array is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Your list only has one element, you forgot to separate each item.

```
wizard_list = ['spider legs', 'toe of frog', 'eye of newt', 'bat wing', 'slug butter', 'snake dandruff']
print(wizard_list)
print(wizard_list[2])
```

Comment: Yep just realized that as I went back through it. Thanks for pointing it out to me however, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just an idiot. I had spaced that if you are creating a list, each item needs it's own single quote.

store_list= ['eggs', 'butter', 'milk']
print(store_list)
eggs, butter, milk
print(store_list[0])
eggs

Answer (score 0):

Joshua, there is a syntax error in your code causing the undesired behavior.

```
 wizard_list = ['spider legs', 'toe of frog', 'eye of newt', 
'bat wing', 'slug butter', 'snake dandruff']
print(wizard_list)
```

You can read more about list and string in this [Guide](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch03.html)